# Securing SSL communication for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, security, ssl

We go about securing communications over SSL for mobile apps. One of the risks of not securing is to let someone sniff header information from HTTP GET/POST requests and obtain username/passwords. But, I have always wondered how it be possible for someone to sniff network packets if mobile devices are exchanging data over 2G/3G, home wifi, etc. Is it only 'not secured' when exchanging data over a public wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you send data over any network there are a lot of points on the line (virtual or physical) where this "sniffing" can happen. The point about public wifi is, it is public :D This means, anybody can get access and is in the same network as all other users. This makes attacks easier. But 2G / 3G is not less vulnerable than public wifi. The data is send other the air. It is encrypted, but this encryption can be "hacked". And, there are a lot of points, the packets for your transmission passes, where it is easy to access the traffic. E.g. there are switches all around, providing so called "maintenance ports", that gives thru each packet, passing this switch. And this can then be used for more than maintenance needs...

Another nice technique is used for oversea connections. There are modules out there, that are "simply" plugged on top of the big oversea cables and let you watch on the ongoing traffic.

You see, additional encryption never hurts :D

Answer (score 0):

First of sending password over HTTP is never a good idea, as hashed password would be better or use something like OAuth/

Second hacker have shown that they can [spoof cell phone tower](http://www.wired.com/2010/07/intercepting-cell-phone-calls/) and capture data from connected device.

Also a major issue the [HTTP response caching](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/10/ios-apps-can-be-hijacked-to-show-fraudulent-content-and-intercept-data/), if you send a malformed header hackers could intercept data which is redirected to their own server.

So using SSL(TLS) and checking that the certificate is valid, not allowing any redirects and you should be OK. Until the next big hack ([heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Simple try to always use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https), at least.

This is simple and relatively protected.